# Can I ask a question about movies with a particular motive?

Tags: discussion, scope

Would it be okay if I asked for examples of movies where there's the motive of learning more than human can normally take? I'm looking for movies like "Limitless" (NZT) or "Matrix" (human brain loading).

Comment: A term for some of what you're referring to is [Transhumanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transhumanism_in_fiction).

Answer (score 9):

No, such questions would be closed as they are off topic on the main site.

> Requests for lists of works or recommendations are off-topic as they do not fit our questions and answers format.

However, feel free to head into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) where someone would likely be happy to help.

Comment: But wait... what if time-traveling robots found a way to expand their consciousness, but Toad slimes Lucy...